# Google Email Group not receiving specific email

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, google-apps, spam

We are currently using a webapp that generates outbound emails, but are experiencing a few issues.

When the system sends an email directly to a Gmail user (eg. john.smith@domain.com) it is received fine. If the email is sent to a Google apps group (eg. finance@domain.com) it is never received by any of the group members.

The "*finance@domain.com*" propogates to approximately 6 users. I have reviewed the Spam folder for a few of them and the email still isn't there either.

If the Google engine does indeed classify the inbound email as spam for a Google group, what does it do with it?

Here's a snippet of the header showing that SPF passes:

```
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of XXXX designates XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX as permitted sender)   client-ip=XXXXX;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of XXXX designates XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX as permitted sender) smtp.mail=XXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be an issue of the mail being marked as spam by the Group, not the users. Essentially, when you leave spam on for a group, it'll get checked there and also at the user level. More informaiton about this can be found [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2567001).

If that doesn't seem to be the root cause, I would check at the [Email log search](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2604578) within the Admin console to see what's going on with a bit more detail.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I never knew about the Email Log search. I couldn't find any of the emails in there which led me to further investigate the Group settings. Turns out it wasn't enabled to accept inbound messages from "public" address outside the domain.